# C# How is my Bitmap using a different MemoryStream then the one specified?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bitmap

I am writing a handler that creates two bitmaps via two separate MemoryStreams and then returns one of those bitmaps as a ByteArrayContent response.

Unfortunately, regardless of which bitmap I choose to return, response is always the first bitmap.

For Example:

- stream1 is initialised from byteArray1. image1 is initialised from stream1.
- stream2 is initialised from byteArray2. image2 is initialised from stream2.

I then intialise finalImage from either image1 or image2. finalImage is then saved to a finalStream MemoryStream object.

finalStream is then returned as a byteArray.

**Note 1:** The above only returns image1. Even if finalImage is initialised using image2.

**Note 2:** If I remove all the code that relates to image1, image 2 is returned as expected.

**Note 3:** This block of code will ultimately be used to return both image1 and image2 as a combined image with the two side by side. Unfortunately it was only ever returning image1 so I've had to refactor the code so as to investigate further. Apologies for the mess.

**Note 4:** The data returned by GetTop5SuppliersChart is different and can be seen by the byte array length.

**Note 5:** I thought this might be a caching issue so I have tried loading the handler via incognito mode and via different browsers with no change in result.

**The below code has been annotated with the stream lengths**

```
HttpResponse r = context.Response;
r.ContentType = "image/png";

byte[] byteArray1 = GetTop5SuppliersChart(brokerPerformanceEmailInformation, false);
//byteArray1.length is 22919
byte[] byteArray2 = GetTop5SuppliersChart(brokerPerformanceEmailInformation, true);
//byteArray2.length is 22375

Bitmap image1 = null;
Bitmap image2 = null;
byte[] chartImage = null;
using (MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream(byteArray1))
{
    //stream1.length is 22919
    image1 = new Bitmap(stream1);

    using (MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream(byteArray2))
    {
        //stream2.length is 22375
        image2 = new Bitmap(stream2);

        using (MemoryStream finalStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var finalImage = new Bitmap(image2);
            finalImage.Save(finalStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);  
            //finalStream.length is 127637

            byteArrayToReturn= finalStream.ToArray();
         }
     }
}
r.Write(new ByteArrayContent(byteArrayToReturn));
```

The GetTop5SuppliersGraphData method returns different data for both image1 and image2.

```
private byte[] GetTop5SuppliersChart(BrokerPerformanceEmailInformation emailInformation, bool showCurrentMonth)
{
    var graphData = GetTop5SuppliersGraphData(emailInformation, showCurrentMonth);

    var myChart = new System.Web.Helpers.Chart(chartwidth, chartHeight, GetPieTheme(false))
    .AddSeries(chartType: "pie",
      xValue: graphData.Series,
      yValues: graphData.Values).Write();

    var chartBytes = myChart.GetBytes();
    return chartBytes;
}
```

To summarise:

Regardless of what is used to create finalImage, byteArrayToReturn will always return image1.

Comment: [*Remarks: You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Bitmap.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_IO_Stream_)

Comment: @GSerg Thankyou, refactored code and same result. Please see the amended code in the OP.

Comment: You're always using `image2` to create a new Image (hard-coded). I cannot say for what reason. The MemoryStream declaration is not relevant here, since you're returning its byte array (a copy of it).

Comment: @Jimi Hi Jimi, this is to illustrate that regardless of what bitmap I use, the data from image1 is always returned.

Comment: This illustrates that you're always returning the bytes of `image2` (a copy of a copy of the original bytes). If this code is supposed to return *a combined Image*, why don't you show that, instead? What does *combined* mean here?

Comment: @Jimi That is the expected response yes, unfortunately it is still returning image1. As mentioned in Note 2, if I remove any reference to image1 then image2 is returned successfully. However, the code as it is in the OP returns image1.

Comment: It doesn't. Post the actual code, the code that should generate the *combined Image*.

Comment: @Jimi I don't want to extend the discussion on this much further. The combining of the two images is currently outside of the scope of this question. 

The question is specifically about why the above code returns the image from bitmap image1 instead of image2.

Comment: Well, it doesn't, so there's no much else do.

Comment: @Jimi I appreciate that the above codeblock is simple and that the finalImage bitmap is initialised using image2. But I promise you that image1 is returned instead. I have spent a lot of time alongside the other developers within my department and posting it here is our last resort.

Comment: Arrays are reference types, and I suspect that has something to do with this. Can you post the code in method `GetTop5SuppliersChart(…)`?

Comment: What is `byteArrayToReturn`, is that the code we're looking at? You mention it once as returning the wrong result.

Comment: The code you presented is 1) wrong from the first Bitmap declaration onward (before that, what happens is unknown) - after *Thankyou, refactored code and same result*, you didn't do what was suggested, the exact opposite. 2) It doesn't do what it's supposed to do 3) it doesn't replicate the alleged *problem*. `image1` is the content of `byteArray1`, what comes after doesn't swap arrays/streams. Maybe it's what you suppose this array contains that gives a *false positive* (or false negative). Or what comes after this. If you want help in debugging a piece of code, post the real code.

Comment: @rfmodulator Please see the updated OP for the GetTop5SuppliersChart method. The chartImage variable was renamed byteArrayToReturn whilst writing this in order to make it more readable (Several days worth of debugging has butchered most of this code) and I didn't rename it after making some amendments. I have also amended the OP with that.

Comment: I agree with Jimi. I'm unable to duplicate your results, (I did not implement `GetTop5SuppliersChart()`, but it couldn't possibly matter). There is nothing wrong with the code, it does exactly what you're telling it to do. If you write `image1` and `image2` out to bmp files, do they actually *look* different? Generally, you wouldn't do this to combine two images anyway, you would get a `Graphics` object, and call a `DrawImage()` method on it.

Comment: @rfmodulator That's understandable. It has completely flummoxed us as well.